# Process,map and collect object in one stream call

Tags: java, stream

I have a list of Object and I want to first process each Object and then map them to another
object and then collect them to a list. Like this:

```
list.stream().forEach(doSomething).map(mapFunction).collect()
```

But Java Stream does not support this,and I wander is there any elegant way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Can you move `doSomething` operation inside `mapFunction`?

Comment: Why not replace `forEach` with `map`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.stream().peek(doSomething).map(mapFunction).collect()
```

Comment: This solution seems pretty good, but I wander why it's called peek(). Is it designed to deal with this situation?

Comment: Yes, you can read the javadoc for this method. It is designed for making chains like this: Stream.of("one", "two", "three", "four")
              .filter(e -> e.length() > 3)
              .peek(e -> System.out.println("Filtered value: " + e))
              .map(String::toUpperCase)
              .peek(e -> System.out.println("Mapped value: " + e))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is a [terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), so you can't continue to work with the stream

> Terminal operations, such as Stream.forEach or IntStream.sum, may traverse the stream to produce a result or a side-effect. After the terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is considered consumed, and can no longer be used;

You can move `doSomething` inside `map` method so it will executed during mapping

In general use [reduction operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) instead

> the forEach() can simply be replaced with a reduction operation that is safer, more efficient, and more amenable to parallelization

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `map` after `forEach` since `forEach` doesn't return a `Stream`.

You can just use your `forEach` logic inside a `map` since it will iterate your entire collection anyways:

```
list.stream().map(o -> {
    // Foreach logic
    System.out.println(o);
            
    // Map
    return o.toString();
});
```